# Email template manager tool

Tags: html, css, email, templates

Not sure this is the right place where to ask such question. This is more a business process query than a programming/developing issue.

Anyway, I am struggling with email marketing templates as the knowledge of the marketing team when it comes to HTML or CSS is almost null.
Therefore, we have hundreds of templates popping all over for anyone's campaigns. It becomes a mess both to update or to use for future campaigns.

That's why I was wondering if a sort of template tool would exist. Something that would easily allow us to assemble and disassemble email templates following marketers' needs without any coding knowledge required.

Many thanks,
Geralt

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are, for me this ones are the most complete and straightforward.
Some of them are a full email marketing tool, but you could open a free account and just use the HTML template designer.

https://www.inkbrush.com/

https://www.mailerlite.com/

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/email-templates/

http://mailchimp.com/features/email-templates/